# iOS Storyboard UIObject won't be displayed

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am quite new in iOS development and I just finished following a series of tutorias to finally start myself. I decided to start from a blank based project to understand all the links and definition that must be made to create a simple view based project. 
So I created the storyboard, add a view in it, create a custom class to implement it, link the class to the view on the identity inspector. I also had to change the "application didFinishLaunchWithOptions" to be sure that my view was loaded correctly by simply removing all codes and leaving the "return YES;" like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Then I added an UIButton in the ViewController.m that I created before and add it to the ViewController's view. When I start the simulator I can see and click the button.
Finally I added a button directly by the storyboard, link it to the ViewController.h but this time it won't display on the simulator. I added several labels, images,... , by the storyboard and none of them can be seen. I added the same content by coding it and it displays correctly this time. What am I missing here?

If I am doing it now it is because I want to be able to add a new UIViewController to any of my project in the future and being able to implement it both with code and the storyboard.
Your help would be much appreciated!
Thanks!
Antoine

Comment: How did you create the storyboard?

Comment: @rdelmar While the project was open I did file>new file>User Interface>Storyboard and changed the name. Is there a better way to add it?

Comment: Have you set that as the application's storyboard in the project summary page?

Comment: @jrturton Yes I also did it and then "validate settings"

Comment: It finally works! Well i change one more time the name of the storyboard and set it as the main storyboard again and the program start working properly. Thanks for the help.